# Spring mvc form:form type data can't cast from Localdate to Date

Tags: java, spring, forms, validation, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a simple "expense tracker" with spring mvc 5 and hibernate 5.

When I post without errors, I redirect towards the view and everything it's all right, but When I post and there is an error, the rendering of the view in the GET method fails, because of this:

InputTag - java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to java.util.Date

How can I fix it?

I tried with converters, with initBinder override methods.. but nothing worked.

The field in the entity is annotated with @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")

The field in mysql is DATETIME. 
I've added an InitBinder to format the localDate in the controller.. 
Plus I can't find a similar issue on stackoverflow.
Deeply thank u!

I'm including the controller code:

```
@Controller
public class ExpensesController {

@Autowired
private ExpenseService expenseService;

@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), true));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/expCounter", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showExpensesCounter(Model model)
{
    String userName = securityService.getLoggedUserUsername();
    List<Expense> expenses = expenseService.findAllByUser(userName);
    model.addAttribute("expenses", expenses);

    if (!model.containsAttribute("expForm")) {
        model.addAttribute("expForm", new Expense());
    }
    return "expenses-counter";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/expCounter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addExpense(@Valid @ModelAttribute("expForm") Expense expense,
    BindingResult result,
    ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.expForm", result);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("expForm", expense);
        return "redirect:expCounter";
    }

    expenseService.save(expense);
    return "redirect:expCounter";
}
}
```

This is the expense entity code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "expense")
public class Expense implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7179454458042397155L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
//    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;

    @NotNull
    @DecimalMax("1000000")
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @PastOrPresent
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "on_date", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private LocalDate spentOnDate;
//Constructor, Getters and Setters omitted for brevity
```

And this is the form:

```
 <form:form method="POST" action="expCounter" modelAttribute="expForm">
<div class="form-row mx-5 my-4 align-items-center text-center">
    <div class="form-group col-4 text-uppercase">
        <label class="control-label" for="description">
            <p><spring:message code="expenses.counter.description"/></p>
        </label>
        <form:input path="description" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors path="description" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-2 text-uppercase ${hasErrors ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <label class="control-label" for="amount">
            <p><spring:message code="expenses.counter.amount"/></p>
        </label>
        <form:input path="amount" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors path="amount" />
    </div>

    <!-- THIS IS THE DATE FIELD-->
    <div class="form-group col-2 text-uppercase">
        <label class="control-label" for="spentOnDate">
            <p><spring:message code="expenses.counter.txdate"/></p>
        </label>
        <spring:message code="expenses.placeholder.ondate" var="ondate.placeholder" />
        <form:input type="date" path="spentOnDate" name="spentOnDate"
                    cssClass="form-control" placeholder='${ondate.placeholder}'/>
        <form:errors path="spentOnDate" />
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-2">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <form:button class="btn btn-secondary">
            <spring:message code="general.button.submit"/>
        </form:button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I this it is a problem of DateFormatting.. because I specified the date format like yyyy-MM-dd  (because in mysql I save it like that..) but when the post fails and I get the view (with the data field filled) spring cannot cast the existing LocalDate(yyyy-MM-dd) to java.util.date... but I don't know how to fix it.

I found a workaround: simply changed input tag from spring's form:form to:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="spentOnDate" placeholder="${ondate.placeholder}"/>
```

It now works but would be a lot better to be able to use spring's form:form tag. Do you know how to fix it?
This way I could use the formatter on the FE.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${expForm.spentOnDate}" var="installDate" pattern="dd/mm/yyyy" />
```